# Required feature ‘scheme’ was not provided (scheme REPL in emacs)

Tags: emacs, scheme

It's probably very easy but I simply can't get a running scheme REPL in emacs.

First I installed *MIT scheme* and added 
`(setq scheme-program-name "my/path/to/bin/mit-scheme.exe")`
to my init.el. But when I typed `M-x` `run-scheme` RET I got the error
`Required feature ‘scheme’ was not provided`

So I installed *quack* and added `(require 'quack)` to my init.el
Now when I start emacs I get the same error:`Required feature ‘scheme’ was not provided`

Am I missing a step?

#### Update

Maybe it simply doesn't work under windows:

> Running Scheme under gnu-emacs If you want to run Scheme as an
>   inferior process in gnu-emacs or xemacs (again, ***this is not an option
>   on Windows machines***), then you'll need to:
>
> ```
> Download the xscheme.elc file. This is a byte-compiled elisp file that tells emacs how to run and interact with MIT Scheme. (Source file
> ```
>
> is xscheme.el in case you're interested.)
>
> ```
> This file should replace the xscheme.elc file that comes with emacs. You'll have to find the appropriate directory on your system.
> ```
>
> On my Mandrake Linux system, this is the directory:
>   /usr/share/emacs/21.3/lisp. (This step is not necessary if you are
>   running MIT/GNU Scheme from the CS department machines.)
>
> ```
> Add the following line to your ~/.emacs file
>
> (load-library "xscheme")
> ```

Source (from 2005): http://www.cs.rpi.edu/academics/courses/fall05/ai/scheme/starting.html

#### Following doesn't work either

> Quick Setup
>
> Here is the short list of instruction's for those of you who want to
>   get started in a hurry. An explanation of each step follows below.
>
> 1. Open up emacs (or any other editor) in you home directory.
> 2. Open up the file ".emacs" and add the following line:   `(set-variable (quote scheme-program-name) "stk")`
> 3. Save the file. You only need to do steps 1-3 once. If you were editing the file in Emacs, restart Emacs.
> 4. Start up Emacs and type the following sequence of keys:
>       `M-x`
>       `run-scheme`
>      A new buffer will open up with stk started inside of it.

Source: http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~gini/1901-07s/emacs_scheme/

Comment: Emacs is telling you that some code tries to use feature `scheme` and it has not been loaded. Does library `quack.el` provide feature `scheme`? If it does, are you sure you loaded the library? Is it even in your `load-path`? If it does not provide feature `scheme`, find a library that does and load it.

Comment: I was told emacs comes with scheme. Maybe that's wrong. As for `load-path`: When I make emacs EVAL `load-path` I get tons of paths. So assuming I knew what file is missing does it matter to which of these load paths I copy the missing file?   (Sorry, Windows user here. My knowledge of emacs is still rudimentary). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Emacs comes with library `scheme.el`. But when started without an init file that library is not loaded. It is autoloaded if you edit at Scheme file that has extension `.scm`, `.stk`, `.ss`, or `.sch` - see variable `auto-mode-alist` (search it for `scheme`). If your file has a different extension then customize that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "required feature scheme was not provided" means that the first "scheme.el" found in your load-path does not contain a provide statement. Either your Emacs installation is broken (unlikely), or (more likely) you've installed some random scheme.el that hides the default one. Find it and remove it. Eg try M-x list-load-path-shadows.

Comment: You were right, there were two scheme.el files. One that contains a provide statement, the other not. Removing the second made the `Required feature scheme was not provided` error go away. But now it says `no such file or directory, scheme` Think I'll stick to the (very) basic MIT scheme console. Nevertheless thank you for your answer.